# Способы перебора различно вложенных списков

Tags: python

Пример списка - [[[1, 2], [3, 4]],  [1]]
То есть, в первом индексе может 4 вложенных в друг друга списков, во втором 2 таких списка.
Какие есть способы, кроме рекурсии, перебрать все элементы списка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да используйте стек или очередь

```
a =  [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [5]]
st = []
st.append(a)
while len(st):
    l = st.pop()
    for x in l:
        if type(x) is list:
            st.append(x)
        else:
            print(x)
```